# qt app that takes in textedit barcode scanned, how to change focus between two fields

Tags: qt, focus, barcode, keyboard-events

So for me the plan is like this:

I scan a barcode, it gets in first textedit; 
I scan another barcode, it gets in the second textedit,
in this case i use focus and keyboard event.

my problem is when i scan first code it is fine  but when I scan the second code, some of letters go to second texedit some go to first texedit.
I don't understand what is the problem 
here is my code

```
void CWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
  if(focusWidget() == ui->lePath && !ui->lePath->text().isEmpty())
  {
    ui->leInformation->setFocus(); //leInformation second edit 
    ui->leInformation->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    ui->leInformation->KeyPressEvent(event);
  }
  else
  {
    ui->lePath->setFocus(); //lePath - first edit text, first code scanned //goes here
    ui->lePath->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    ui->lePath->KeyPressEvent(event);
  }
}
```

like is a strange think cause sometimes works sometimes no, if both codes scanned have digits they work but if the second scanned code has uppercase letters they go from the first uppercase letters they are wrote to first edit. but if they are lowercase they are fine again. I m thinking it is a problem with keyboard event how they deal with uppercase. somehow maybe with shift, and they change between two edits. 
if there is someone who has an idea on how i can properly write that keyboard event, please help thanks

[image]

here B should have been on the second. I'm being sure on how uppercase are being entered on keyboard event is about shift + letter and shift moves you to the other edit but how i can change this

Comment: Your scanning is going faster than your code.

Comment: No. The problem is with the event on shift that moves focus between two edits :)

Comment: How your are _scanning_ :)

Comment: Is  a normal code scanner. nothing special, is just about this shift

Comment: How is your normal (barcode) scanner connected? usb keyboard?

Comment: yes, exactly...

Comment: and you are pressing the "Shift key" to switch focus by the (other) standard keyboard?

Comment: no, my problem is like this: i scan first code for the first edit text, if my code has uppercase the rest of code from the first uppercase letter gets  to second edit, because of the way shift event is working and uppercase letter are wrote

Comment: If the scanner is connected as usb keyboard .. then why you are catching the keyboard events? normal scanners give output to anything be it your widget or any external element having focus?

Comment: You didnt understood my problem i think, if i dont use that keyboard event they will not change focus between them, i have two edit text that i want to scan

Comment: Is your scanner configured for time delay between character feeds ,, like how many m. seconds delay between each character passed?

Comment: no, i dont have time delay, i dont really know how to do that

Comment: That's why I told you in the begging that your scanner might be faster than your processing of events .. this is possible, another thing to consider in your code .. your checking **two** conditions  one of them for emptiness of text ... this condition will be satisfied only for first character .. when second character comes it will not ... this may be a nother problem

Comment: Maybe, but my problem is what happens with uppercase letter and shift and keypressed event

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "Shift" .. but characters are sent by their codes, also in your screen first characters are caps (AF) and still in first text

Comment: Yes,  but the problem is with uppercase letters and how they are managed my keypressevent, cause without uppercase everything is fine

Comment: Don't be so sure :), Can you remove feeding the characters from your code `ui->leInformation->KeyPressEvent(event);` , and the other one.. practically they should not be used with such scanners.

Comment: I changed and nothing happens how i could configure that time delay?

Comment: Your scanner manual should tell. if characters are still coming then be sure you don't need those lines your removed.

Comment: Did you find it? is it realted to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810731/qt-how-i-can-check-difference-of-timestamp-between-2-keypressevent) .. ?

Comment: i made an event filter and time bettween key pressed but now my problem is when  i try to write on my edit from keyboard