# qt how to change shift key press event to not move between two edits

Tags: qt, focus

my problem is with a code scanner and using focus with keypressevent
i have two edits and my keyboard event is like this

```
void CWidget::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent *event)
{
  if(focusWidget() == ui->lePath && !ui->lePath->text().isEmpty())
  {
    ui->leInformation->setFocus();
    ui->leInformation->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    ui->leInformation->KeyPressEvent(event);
  }
  else
  {
    ui->lePath->setFocus();
    ui->lePath->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
    ui->lePath->KeyPressEvent(event);
  }
}
```

if i scan a code with digits and lowercase letters everything is fine.
if i scan with uppercase letters some of text goes to the other edit 
because of the way uppercase are managed with shift, shift changing between the two edits too. how i can make them not change between those too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [qt app that takes in edittext code bar scanned, how to change focus between two edits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49796174/qt-app-that-takes-in-edittext-code-bar-scanned-how-to-change-focus-between-two)

Comment: What is the difference with your previous question?

Comment: cause i found my problem

Comment: And then why do not you post an answer?

Comment: cause i dont know how to solve the problem

Comment: Then the correct thing is that you update your previous question indicating what you have advanced: code and/or conclusions and not create a new question.