# qt how i can check difference of timestamp between 2 keypressevent

Tags: qt, timestamp, focus

I'm trying to change focus between two edits when the time difference between 2 keys is greater than 100ms. How can I memorize the last key input if the `keyPressed(..)` function is every time a key is inputted ?

Comment: Store the last time as a member variable in your class and compare it with the current time, when a key press event occurs.

Comment: I would suggest to use `QTime`. In each keypress you check `QTime::elapsed() >= 100` and change focus if necessary. Then call `QTime::restart()`.

Comment: [`QElapsedTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qelapsedtimer.html) is what you need. It is more accurate then `QTime`. @Bobur

Comment: @DmitrySazonov you right! Thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use `QTime` for this, as it depends on the system clock. I would use `QElapsedTimer` or `QTimer`.

Example with `QTimer`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Widget(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent)
    {
        setLayout(new QHBoxLayout);
        layout()->addWidget(&line_edit1);
        layout()->addWidget(&line_edit2);
        focus_timer.setInterval(100);
        focus_timer.setSingleShot(true);
        connect(&line_edit1, &QLineEdit::textEdited, &focus_timer, QOverload<>::of(&QTimer::start));
        connect(&line_edit2, &QLineEdit::textEdited, &focus_timer, QOverload<>::of(&QTimer::start));
        connect(&focus_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [&]
        {
            line_edit1.hasFocus() ? line_edit2.setFocus() : line_edit1.setFocus();
        });
    }
private:
    QLineEdit line_edit1;
    QLineEdit line_edit2;
    QTimer focus_timer;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Comment: is a cool idea, but for me is a different problem i want to focus on each edit as long the difference between two keys pressed is  less than an value.

Comment: i need this for a code bar scanner to scan for each edit and change focus when he finished for one edit

Comment: @AlexandraTupu But that is what my example does. After 100ms passes since the last input, it gives focus to the next line edit. Are you saying you want to force the focus on a specific line edit, and not allow it to lose focus until input has been given and 100ms has elapsed?

Comment: i mean about time between two keys pressed, like when i scanned first bar code to be inserted in my first edit and after change focus to next edit an scan for the second one

Comment: Well that is what this example does. It will not change focus until 100ms has elapsed between two inputs. As long as the time between the last and current input is less than 100ms, it will keep the focus.

Comment: ok, i understand now, thanks, sorry, i dont have so much experience with qt